# Are the following sets subgroups of $S_n$? What's their order? Are they abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Are the following subsets of the group $S_n$ subgroups? What's their order? Are they abelian?

1. $\{(12)^k(34)^l | l,k \geq 1 \}$
2. $\{w \in S_n | w^2=id\}$

So I got a solution for 1:

1. Yes it's a subset. For $l,k=2$ you can see the unit is there. For any permutation of the form $(12)^k(34)^l$, its inverse is $(12)^k(34)^l$, since they are disjoint and of order 2. Let there $k,l,m,n \geq 1$, so  $(12)^k(34)^l(12)^m(34)^n=(12)^{k+m}(34)^{l+n}$. And since $k,l,m,n \geq 1$ so are their sums. It's of order 4: $\{id, (12), (34), (12)(34)\}$ and is abelian, since it's a set of disjoint circles - which are commutitive.

Is it correct?

With 2 I had troubles. It seems like an abelian subgroup, but I had trouble coming up with order...

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: For 2., your subset has elements like $(12)$ and $(23)$, so their product has to be in the subset.

Comment: @charlie The second one doesn't seem Abelian, since (1 2) and (2 3) are in it, as Daenerys Naharis mentioned. For basically the same reason it doesn't even seem to be a subgroup.